# Correct use of present participles

Tags: adjectives, word-order, present-participles

Does this sentence make sense?

> For example, bags at an airport are x-rayed to see if any dangerous are inside without having to be opened and looked in each one.

Answer (score 1):

1 - You can either say "dangerous items " or "anything dangerous ", but not "any dangerous", as you need a noun to accompany the adjective "dangerous"

2 - The position of "each one" in your sentence seems wrong. General Subject-verb word order requirement is the reason here I think: subject "each one", verb "having".

For example, bags at an airport are x-rayed to see if any dangerous **items** are inside without **each one** having to be opened and looked in.